# JQuery DataTable Column Filter using Checkboxes

Tags: php, datatables, server-side-scripting

How to implement JQuery DataTable Column Filter using Checkboxes server side scripting? Please tell me whether the filtering is done from serveside.php or in my HTML file using javascript. I want to implement like https://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn-history/r77/trunk/checkbox.html but using server side scripting.

Comment: anybody there for help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code for datatables initialization in HTML file. One thing must be kept in mind the initialization is done not on local server. The code must be run on remote server.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $dt = $('#example1').dataTable({
"bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "sAjaxSource": "server.php",
        "aaSorting": [[3, "desc"]],
        "fnServerData": function(sUrl, aoData, fnCallback) {
        $.ajax({
        "url": sUrl,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": fnCallback,
                "dataType": "json",
                "cache": false
        });
        }
});
        //$dt.fnDraw();

        $dt.columnFilter({sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
                aoColumns: [
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                {
                type: "checkbox",
                        values:
                        [
                        {value: '3', label: 'New'},
                        {value: '0', label: 'Pending'},
                        {value: '1', label: 'Active'},
                        {value: '2', label: 'Inactive'},
                        ]
                },
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                ]
        });
```